# Asymptotically invariant maps and strongly ergodic actions

Tags: gr.group-theory, ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Let $\Gamma$ be a countable group which acts strongly ergodically on a probability measure space $(X,\mu)$. Let $\sigma_k:X \rightarrow Y$ be a sequence of measurable functions into a complete metric space $(Y,d_Y)$ which is separable.

Suppose that for $\mu$-almost every $x \in X$ we have that $\lim_{k \to \infty} d_Y(\sigma_k(x),\sigma_k(\gamma.x))=0$ for every $\gamma \in \Gamma$, where $\gamma.x$ denotes the action of the element $\gamma$ on $x$.

What can we say about the map $\sigma_k$? Could it be true that these maps are asymptotically constant, in the sense that $\lim_{k \to \infty} d_Y(\sigma_k(x),\sigma_k(y))=0$ for almost every $x,y \in X$?

Comment: What does it mean for a group to act strongly ergodically?

Comment: A group $\Gamma$ acts strongly ergodically on a measure space $(X,\mu)$ if given a sequence of measurable sets $\{A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mu(A_n \Delta \gamma.A_n)=0$, then it holds $\lim_{n \to \mathbb{N}} \mu(A_n)(1-\mu(A_n))=0$. Intuitively, any sequence of measurable sets which is asymptotically invariant must have either full or null measure at infinity.

Comment: So,in particular, we are not talking about the measure-preserving action of an amenable group?

Comment: For amenable groups it should be known that ergodic actions cannot be strongly ergodic, so in particular we are not talking of actions of amenable groups. You are perfectly right.

Answer (score 1):

The maps $(\sigma _n)$ are asymptotically constant, in the sense that there is a sequence $(y_n)$ in $Y$ for which $d(\sigma _n , y_n )\rightarrow 0$ in measure, in each of the following cases:

$\bullet$ $(Y,d)$ is compact,

$\bullet$ $(Y,d)$ is an ultrametric space,

$\bullet$ $Y$ is a locally compact second countable group with finite asymptotic dimension (and $d$ is a compatible proper left-invariant metric on $Y$).

The assumption that the convergence $d(\gamma \cdot \sigma _n , \sigma _n )\rightarrow 0$ is pointwise a.e. for each $\gamma \in \Gamma$ (where $(\gamma\cdot \sigma _n )(x)=\sigma _n (\gamma ^{-1}x)$) can be relaxed to assuming that this convergence is in measure for each $\gamma \in \Gamma$.

---

$\bullet$ Suppose $(Y,d)$ is compact. I'll sketch an argument for this case using ultraproducts (a different argument can be obtained by seeing this as a special case of Lemma 2.4 of [this paper by Adrian Ioana and myself](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05357)). Note that it suffices to prove the conclusion along a subsequence of $(\sigma _n)$. By assumption $\int _X d(\sigma _n (g^{-1}x), \sigma _n(x)) \, d\mu \rightarrow 0$ for all $g\in \Gamma$. Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\mathbb{N}$. Then the strong ergodicity of the action $\Gamma \curvearrowright (X,\mu )$ is equivalent to ergodicity of the ultrapower action $\Gamma \curvearrowright (X_{\mathcal{U}},\mu _{\mathcal{U}})$. Since $Y$ is compact we can define a map $\sigma :X_{\mathcal{U}}\rightarrow Y$ by $\sigma ([x_n])=\lim _{n\rightarrow \mathcal{U}}\sigma _n (x_n)$, which is measurable (here $[x_n]\in X_{\mathcal{U}}$ denotes the equivalence class of a sequence $(x_n)\in X^{\mathbb{N}}$), and for each $g\in \Gamma$ we have

$\int _{X_{\mathcal{U}}}d(\sigma (g[x_n]),\sigma ([x_n]))\, d\mu _{\mathcal{U}} = \lim _{n\rightarrow \mathcal{U}}\int _X d (\sigma _n(gx), \sigma _n (x))\, d\mu = 0$.

Therefore, by ergodicity there is some $y\in Y$ such that $\lim _{n\rightarrow \mathcal{U}}\sigma _n (x_n)= y$ for a.e. $[x_n]\in X_{\mathcal{U}}$. Thus, $\lim _{n\rightarrow \mathcal{U}}\int _X d (\sigma _n (x),y ) \, d\mu = \int _{X_{\mathcal{U}}} d(\sigma ([x_n]),y) \, d\mu _{\mathcal{U}} = 0$, which finishes the proof. $\square$

---

Note that this gives a proof of the well known fact that strong ergodicity of $\Gamma \curvearrowright (X,\mu )$ implies that if $f_n \in L^{\infty}(X,\mu )$ satisfies $\sup _n \| f_n \| _{\infty}< \infty$ and $\| g\cdot f_n - f_n \| _1\rightarrow 0$ for all $g\in \Gamma$, then $\| f_n - \int f_n \, d\mu \| _1\rightarrow 0$. (Here, $(g\cdot f_n)(x)= f_n(g^{-1}x)$.)

---

$\bullet$ Suppose $(Y,d)$ is a (separable) ultrametric space. The argument in this case is essentially the same as Lemma 2.5 from [this paper of Adrian Ioana](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.3026). Given $\epsilon >0$, it is enough to find a finite $F\subseteq \Gamma$ and $\delta >0$ such that if $\sigma :X\rightarrow Y$ is a measurable map satisfying $\mu ( \{ x : d(\sigma (g^{-1}x),\sigma (x)) <\delta \} )>1-\delta$ for all $g\in F$, then there is some $y\in Y$ with $\mu ( \{ x : d(\sigma (x),y)<\epsilon \} )>1-\epsilon$. We may assume that $\epsilon < 1/3$.

By strong ergodicity we can find a finite $F\subseteq \Gamma$ and $\delta >0$ such that if $A\subseteq X$ satifies $\mu (gA\triangle A )<\delta$ for all $g\in F$ then either $\mu (A)<\epsilon$ or $\mu (A)>1-\epsilon$. We may assume that $\delta <\epsilon$. Suppose that $\sigma : X\rightarrow Y$ is as above, using this $\delta$.

Let $\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}$ denote the collection of all $\epsilon$-balls in $Y$, so that $\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}$ is a countable partition of $Y$ with $d(A,B)\geq \epsilon$ for distinct $A,B\in \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}$. Let $\tau (x) \in \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}$ be the unique element containing $\sigma (x)$. Then for each $g\in F$, the assumption on $\sigma$ implies that $\mu ( \{ x : \tau (g^{-1}x)=\tau (x) \} ) > 1-\delta$, and hence for every subset $\mathcal{D}$ of $\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}$ we have $\max _{g\in F} \mu (g\tau ^{-1}(\mathcal{D})\triangle \tau ^{-1}(\mathcal{D}) )<\delta$. So, by our choice of $\delta$, the measure $\tau _*\mu$ on $\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}$ takes values in the interval $[0,\epsilon )\cup (1-\epsilon ,1]$, and hence there is some $B\in \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}$ with $\mu (\tau ^{-1}(B))>1-\epsilon$. Fixing some $y\in B$, this means that $\mu ( \{ x : d(\sigma (x),y)<\epsilon \} )>1-\epsilon$, as was to be shown. $\square$.

---

$\bullet$ The last case mentioned above is a consequence of the following **Lemma:** Let $\Gamma\curvearrowright (X,\mu )$ be strongly ergodic, let $(Y,d)$ be a separable metric space, and let $\sigma _n : X\rightarrow Y$ be a sequence of measurable maps with $d(g\cdot \sigma _n , \sigma _n)\rightarrow 0$ in measure for all $g\in \Gamma$. Suppose that $\mathcal{C}$ is a countable cover of $Y$ that can be written as a finite union $\mathcal{C}=\bigcup _{i=0}^m\mathcal{C}_i$ where for each $i$ the collection $\mathcal{C}_i$ is *uniformly disjoint*, i.e., there is some $r>0$ such that $d(A,B)\geq r$ for all distinct $A,B\in \mathcal{C}_i$. Then there exists a sequence $(D_n)$ in $\mathcal{C}$ such that $d(\sigma _n , D_n )\rightarrow 0$ in measure.

For the proof of this lemma, after replacing $d$ by the uniformly equivalent metric $d/(1+d)$ if necessary, we may assume that $d\leq 1$. For each $i$, letting $C_i=\bigcup \mathcal{C}_i$, we have $\| d(g\cdot \sigma _n , C_i ) - d(\sigma _n , C_i ) \| _1\leq \| d(g\cdot \sigma _n ,\sigma _n ) \| _1 \rightarrow 0$ for all $g\in G$. Thus (by the note after the compact case) $\| d(\sigma _n, C_i ) - \widetilde{d}(\sigma _n, C_i ) \| _1 \rightarrow 0$ for all $i\leq m$, where $\widetilde{d}(\sigma _n, C_i ) = \int d(\sigma _n (x),C_i )\, d\mu$.  Since $C_0,\dots , C_m$ cover $Y$, this implies that for every $\epsilon >0$ there are at most finitely many $n$ for which $\min _{i\leq m} \widetilde{d}(\sigma _n , C_i) \geq \epsilon$.  Thus, there must be some sequence $(i_n)$ such that $\widetilde{d}(\sigma _n, C_{i_n} ) \rightarrow 0$. By perturbing the $\sigma _n$ an asymptotically negligible amount, we may assume that $\sigma _n(x) \in C_{i_n}$ for all $x\in X$ and all $n$. The rest of the proof is exactly as in the ultrametric case (with $\mathcal{C}$ here playing the role of $\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}$ there), using that each $\mathcal{C}_i$ is uniformly disjoint. $\square$

This applies to the case of a proper metric space $(Y,d)$ of finite asymptotic dimension whose isometry group acts transitively: the finite asymptotic dimension hypothesis is only used once to obtain a single countable cover $\mathcal{C}$ of $Y$ by sets of uniformly bounded diameter, which can be expressed as a finite union $\mathcal{C}=\bigcup _{i=0}^m \mathcal{C}_i$ where each $\mathcal{C}_i$ is uniformly disjoint. By the above lemma, given a sequence $(\sigma _n)$ under consideration, we can find $D_n \in \mathcal{C}$ with $d(\sigma _n , D_n ) \rightarrow 0$ in measure, so by making an asymptotically negligible change we can assume that $\sigma _n (x)\in D_n$ for all $n$. Since the isometry group acts transitively and the $D_n$ are uniformly bounded, we can isometrically translate all the $D_n$ into a single compact ball, and apply the compact case (then translate back) to finish the proof. $\square$

---

As can be seen from the proof, the assumption of finite asymptotic dimension appears to be overkill. I don't know what happens with general complete separable metric spaces. Perhaps there could be a counterexample using some kind of measure concentration argument, but at the moment I don't have one.

---

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, then for almost every $x$, $\sigma_k(x)\to \sigma(\gamma x)$ for all $\gamma\in G$. But the $\sigma_k(x)\to \sigma(x)$ also since $Id\in G$. Hence for a.e. $x$, $\sigma(\gamma x)=\sigma x$ for all $\gamma\in G$. That is, $\sigma$ is an a.e. invariant function. But strong ergodicity implies that an a.e. invariant function is a.e. constant.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the question. Clearly you do not know a priori any convergence of the sequence $\sigma_k$ to a measurable map $\sigma$, because otherwise, as you pointed out, you could apply the ergodic property to the limit function and get that the limit is essentially constant.